# What this is Poisson or Binomial

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

From a research is known that average 1% of drivers are causing a car accident every year. One safe company has 1000 drivers that are been on them. What is the possibility that the company should pay for more than 2 accidents of their customers in the next year. What I did , I thought I have 1% on average so to find

what I did: (Poisson)

$ λ =0.01 \cdot 1000=10$, so I have λ

$$f(x)=e^{-λ} \cdot λ^x/x!= e^{-10} \cdot10^2/2!$$

Comment: I assume Poisson

Comment: ok thank you :)

Comment: I think Poisson too. But by calculating P (X> 2).

Comment: how to use  P (X> 2)?

Comment: You want a number of accidents> 2. $P(X>2)=1-P(X\leq 2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette i am not sure if i got it ,if you can answer it so i can tick it as an answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approximate by Poisson distribution of parameter 10.

We have $f(x)=e^{-10}\frac{10^x}{x!}$

$f(x)$ is the probability to get x accidents in a year.

The question is:

What is the possibility that the company should pay for **more than 2 accidents** of their customers in the next year.

We must calculate the probability to have 0 or 1 or 2 accidents and the result is:

$1-f(0)-f(1)-f(2)$

Answer (score 0):

The probability you have exactly $0$ accidents in a year is $(0.99)^{1000} (0.01)^0$.

The probability you have exactly $1$ accident in a year is ${1000 \choose 1} (0.99)^{999} (0.01)^1$.

The probability you have exactly $2$ accidents in a year is ${1000 \choose 2}(0.99)^{998} (0.01)^2$.

Sum these up to get the probability of getting $0,1,2$ accidents.  Then compute 1.0 minus that probability to find the probability of getting more than two accidents per year.